# C#: Method Invoke never returns

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke

I've got a threaded invoke call that never returns.

The thread runs just fine right up until I call the line that ways, "`owner.Invoke(methInvoker);`"

When debugging, I can slowly step, step, step, but once I hit `owner.Invoke`... it's Over!

```
Control owner;
public event ReportCeProgressDelegate ProgressChanged;

public void ReportProgress(int step, object data) {
  if ((owner != null) && (ProgressChanged != null)) {
    if (!CancellationPending) {
      ThreadEventArg e = new ThreadEventArg(step, data);
      if (owner.InvokeRequired) {
        MethodInvoker methInvoker = delegate { ProgressChanged(this, e); };
        owner.Invoke(methInvoker);
      } else {
        ProgressChanged(this, e);
      }
    } else {
      mreReporter.Set();
      mreReporter.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

FYI: This is a custom class that mimics the `BackgroundWorker` class, which is not available on controls that do not have Forms.

Thinking Invoke might not be required, I manually stepped the cursor in the debugger over that part of the code and tried calling `ProgressChanged` directly, but VS2010's debugger threw a cross thread exception.

**EDIT:**

Due to the first 3 comments I have received, I wanted to update with my `ProgressChanged` method:

```
worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, ThreadEventArg e) {
  if (progressBar1.Style != ProgressBarStyle.Continuous) {
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    object data = e.Data;
    if (data != null) {
      progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    }
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
  }
  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
};
```

There is a breakpoint on the first line of the *anonymous method*, but it never gets hit either.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a more complete listing of the call to the thread:

```
List<TableData> tList = CollectTablesFromForm();
if (0 < tList.Count) {
  using (SqlCeReporter worker = new SqlCeReporter(this)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tList.Count; i++) {
      ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
      worker.StartThread += SqlCeClass.SaveSqlCeDataTable;
      worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, ThreadEventArg e) {
        if (progressBar1.Style != ProgressBarStyle.Continuous) {
          progressBar1.Value = 0;
          object data = e.Data;
          if (data != null) {
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
          }
          progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        }
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
      };
      worker.ThreadCompleted += delegate(object sender, ThreadResultArg e) {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        if (e.Error == null) {
          if (e.Cancelled) {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Save Action was Cancelled.", "Save Table " + tList[i].TableName);
          }
        } else {
          MessageBox.Show(this, e.Error.Message, "Error Saving Table " + tList[i].TableName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        mre.Set();
      };
      worker.RunWorkerAsync(tList[i]);
      progressBar1.Value = 0;
      progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
      progressBar1.Visible = true;
      Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
      mre.WaitOne();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this isn't overkill! I hate presenting too much information, because then I get people critiquing my style. :)

Comment: Invoked methos is totally different process, add break point at the start of your method so u will be able to enter it.

Comment: The event loop could be tied up elsewhere.  I would check for anything blocking in another handler.

Comment: Have you paused the debugger while it is hanging around, gone to the "Threads" debugging Window, double-clicked each thread, looked at its call stack and place of execution and looked for 1) deadlocks (e.g. code is paused on "Wait" or "WaitAll" in more than one place) 2) general strange operations.  Take note of the thread ID of the GUI thread prior to the application freeze and see especially what it is doing after the freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  worker.RunWorkerAsync(tList[i]);
  //...
  mre.WaitOne();
```

That's a guaranteed deadlock.  The delegate you pass to Control.Begin/Invoke() can only run when the UI thread is idle, having re-entered the message loop.  Your UI thread isn't idle, it is blocked on the WaitOne() call.  That call can't complete until your worker thread completes.  Your worker thread can't complete until the Invoke() call is completed.  That call can't complete until the UI thread goes idle.  Deadlock city.

Blocking the UI thread is fundamentally a wrong thing to do.  Not just because of .NET plumbing, COM already requires it to never block.  That's why BGW has a RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: That's what Brian's comment lead me to think as well. Looks like I need to redesign parts of my class.

Comment: Well, just delete the mre.WaitOne() call.  Then start thinking about how you want to handle the 'worker is done' scenario.  You are a bit doomed to re-invent BGW.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have deadlocked the UI and worker threads. `Control.Invoke` marshals the execution of a delegate onto the UI thread by posting a message to the UI thread's message queue and then waits for that message to be processed which in turn means the execution of the delegate has to complete before `Control.Invoke` returns. But, what if your UI thread is busy doing something else beside dispatching and processing messages? I can see from your code that a `ManualResetEvent` may be in play here. Is your UI thread blocked on a call to `WaitOne` by chance? If so that could definitely be the problem. Since `WaitOne` does not pump messages it will block the UI thread which will lead to a deadlock when `Control.Invoke` is called from your worker thread.

If you want your `ProgressChanged` event to behave like it does with `BackgroundWorker` then you will need to call `Control.Invoke` to get those event handlers onto the UI thread. That is the way `BackgroundWorker` works anyway. Of course, you do not *have* to mimic the `BackgroundWorker` class exactly in that respect as long as you are prepared to have the callers do their own marshaling when handling the `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: The `ManualResetEvent` referenced in the first block of code is localized to the custom thread class only ...and so far, I haven't really used it. It seemed like a good way of cancelling a very lengthy process if I needed to.

The main thread (UI), on the other hand, also has a `ManualResetEvent` of its own. The code block's task is to save 1 or more data tables on the form, and I want to prevent from having multiple tables saving to a local SQL CE database at one time.

See **EDIT 2** for that code (posted shortly).